# Facebook login fails with facebook app installed

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm new to android development. I've downloaded facebook sdk 3.0.1, and using the sample code to log in. The problem is, that if facebook app is installed the authentication fails.
(otherwise it works just fine)
after pressing the log in button I get to onActivityResult with status CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED.
of course I'm not typing the password, it's done automatically through facebook's app, and the facebook app is logged in and works properly.
I couldn't find a solution..
please help me :)

this is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    instance = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonLoginToFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginToFacebook);
    tvWellcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWellcome);

    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback,
                    savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                    .setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }

    updateView();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
    updateView();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}

private void updateView() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenStartPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        buttonLoginToFacebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickLogin();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                .setCallback(statusCallback));
        updateView();
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}


public void onClickLogout() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        updateView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you setup your debug key hash and full class name on Facebook's app settings dashbaord? see steps 5 and 6 in the [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) doc.

Comment: Yes I did, would a connection without the facebook app installed have worked if I didn't? Thank you for the reply

Comment: I rechecked the settings on the developer page, apparently the package name didn't match. When I fixed it I received an error from facebook while trying to log in  to the app saying the key hash don't match. I copied their key hash and now it finally worked!! thank you Amir!

Comment: Hey @Amir Naor I tried implementing the FB login flow with the UILifeCycleHelper and in certain instances, the `data` param which would normally have a field `mMap`, which contains the FB response, is null.  Why would this be happening?